# Extension theorem for locally Lipschitz functions

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let A be a subset of a metric space $(X,d)$ and f be a real valued locally lipschitz function on A. Does there exists a real valued locally lipschitz function on X which is an extension of f? or under what conditions on A can we have such extension ?

Comment: Isn’t $(0..∞) → ℝ,~x ↦ 1/x$ locally Lipschitz?

Comment: I got your point. What about extending a continuous function on a closed set A to a locally lipschitz function on the whole of X?